# can we use RQT inbuilt plugin to create our new custom plugin?

Tags: ros-kinetic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Can we use RQT inbuild plugin like rqt_plot, rqt_steering or their API to build new RQT application/plugin ?

Thanks & Regards
Yogesh Dusane

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345136/can-we-use-rqt-inbuilt-plugin-to-create-our-new-custom-plugin-?/) by [Yogesh Dusane](https://answers.ros.org/users/52089/yogesh-dusane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Yogesh Dusane,

You can use the [RQT functionalities](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Create%20your%20new%20rqt%20plugin) to generate a new plugin for this tool. However the new plugin will only work in the operational environment provided by RQT, thus you will not be able to use it as an independent component.

On the other hand, you have the possibility to generate a package that integrates ROS functionalities and Qt if that is what you want. You can find an example of this set up [here](http://wiki.ros.org/qt_create).

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yogesh Dusane](https://answers.ros.org/users/52089/yogesh-dusane/) on 2020-02-27**:
any possibility to use rqt_plot, rqt_steering or their API in my own custom plugin for rqt?

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-02-27**:
I think that is not supported since the plugins are self contained.

A workaround would be to use their implementation into your plugin and add your custom functionalities.

**Comment by [Yogesh Dusane](https://answers.ros.org/users/52089/yogesh-dusane/) on 2020-02-27**:
Thank you for your confirmation.

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-02-27**:
Great!

If you consider the answer proposed good, mark it as correct please.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-27**:
Could you please mark the question as answered by ticking the checkmark (✓) to the left of the answer if you feel it has been answered? Thanks.